# Naudio BadDeviceId calling waveInOpen Error in C#

Tags: c#, .net, record, naudio, wave

I am trying to record system audio.

Why this code returns exception. error message is BadDeviceId calling waveInOpen...

Is there something wrong in code ? Or should I make something out of code? I enabled microphone device on computer (from recording devices) but there is no microphone plugged in. I just want to record system audio.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NAudio;
using NAudio.Wave;


namespace SeleniumDeneme.Classes
{
    class RecorderForVideo
    {

        public WaveIn waveSource = null;
        public WaveFileWriter waveFile = null;


        public RecorderForVideo() { }

        public void CreateObjectsForRecord() 
        {
             waveSource = new WaveIn();
             waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
             waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
             waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSource_RecordingStopped);

             waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(@"C:\Users\BerkayS\Desktop\Test0001.wav", waveSource.WaveFormat);


             waveSource.StartRecording();


        }

        void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveFile != null)
            {
                waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
                waveFile.Flush();
            }
        }

        void waveSource_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveSource != null)
            {
                waveSource.Dispose();
                waveSource = null;
            }

            if (waveFile != null)
            {
                waveFile.Dispose();
                waveFile = null;
            }


        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved.

I plugged in a microphone to computer and problem is solved. So the code works completely.